# tailwind classes doesn't work out of app folder

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm new to Tailwind and I'm using this framework with next.js .
when I want to use tailwind class, it won't work unless I use it in my app folder first!
for example, if I want to use *bg-green-500* for my component folder (outside of the app folder) I should try it in my app folder, and then it will be available for another folder outside of the app folder

I have tried some ways like uninstalling and installing the package and ... but unfortunately it didn't work.

page.tsx

```
import { Hero } from '@/component/template/index'

export default function Home () {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Hero />
    </div>
  )
}
```

layout.tsx

```
import "./globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="">{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

globals.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
}

/* START: General styles */
.max-width {
  @apply max-w-[1440px] mx-auto;
}

.padding-x {
  @apply sm:px-16 px-6;
}

.padding-y {
  @apply py-4;
}

.flex-center {
  @apply flex items-center justify-center;
}

.flex-between {
  @apply flex justify-between items-center;
}

.custom-btn {
  @apply flex flex-row relative justify-center items-center py-3 px-6 outline-none;
}
/* END: General styles */

/* START: Hero styles */
.hero {
  @apply flex xl:flex-row flex-col gap-5 relative z-0 max-w-[1440px] mx-auto;
}

.hero__title {
  @apply 2xl:text-[72px] sm:text-[64px] text-[50px] font-extrabold;
}

.hero__subtitle {
  @apply text-[27px] text-black-100 font-light mt-5;
}

.hero__image-container {
  @apply xl:flex-[1.5] flex justify-end items-end w-full xl:h-screen;
}

.hero__image {
  @apply relative xl:w-full w-[90%] xl:h-full h-[590px] z-0;
}

.hero__image-overlay {
  @apply absolute xl:-top-24 xl:-right-1/2 -right-1/4 bg-hero-bg bg-repeat-round -z-10 w-full xl:h-screen h-[590px] overflow-hidden;
}
/* END: Hero styles */

/* START: Home styles */

.home__text-container {
  @apply flex flex-col items-start justify-start gap-y-2.5 text-black-100;
}

.home__filters {
  @apply mt-12 w-full flex-between items-center flex-wrap gap-5;
}

.home__filter-container {
  @apply flex justify-start flex-wrap items-center gap-2;
}

.home__cars-wrapper {
  @apply grid 2xl:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 w-full gap-8 pt-14;
}

.home__error-container {
  @apply mt-16 flex justify-center items-center flex-col gap-2;
}
/* END: Home styles */

/* START: Car Card styles */
.car-card {
  @apply flex flex-col p-6 justify-center items-start text-black-100 bg-primary-blue-100 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-md rounded-3xl;
}

.car-card__content {
  @apply w-full flex justify-between items-start gap-2;
}

.car-card__content-title {
  @apply text-[22px] leading-[26px] font-bold capitalize;
}

.car-card__price {
  @apply flex mt-6 text-[32px] leading-[38px] font-extrabold;
}

.car-card__price-dollar {
  @apply self-start text-[14px] leading-[17px] font-semibold;
}

.car-card__price-day {
  @apply self-end text-[14px] leading-[17px] font-medium;
}

.car-card__image {
  @apply relative w-full h-40 my-3 object-contain;
}

.car-card__icon-container {
  @apply flex group-hover:invisible w-full justify-between text-grey;
}

.car-card__icon {
  @apply flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2;
}

.car-card__icon-text {
  @apply text-[14px] leading-[17px];
}

.car-card__btn-container {
  @apply hidden group-hover:flex absolute bottom-0 w-full z-10;
}
/* END: Car Card styles */

/* START: Car Details styles */
.car-details__dialog-panel {
  @apply relative w-full max-w-lg max-h-[90vh] overflow-y-auto transform rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left shadow-xl transition-all flex flex-col gap-5;
}

.car-details__close-btn {
  @apply absolute top-2 right-2 z-10 w-fit p-2 bg-primary-blue-100 rounded-full;
}

.car-details__main-image {
  @apply relative w-full h-40 bg-pattern bg-cover bg-center rounded-lg;
}
/* END: Car Details styles */

/* START: Custom Filter styles */
.custom-filter__btn {
  @apply relative w-full min-w-[127px] flex justify-between items-center cursor-default rounded-lg bg-white py-2 px-3 text-left shadow-md sm:text-sm border;
}

.custom-filter__options {
  @apply absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm;
}
/* END: Custom Filter styles */

/* START: Footer styles */
.footer {
  @apply flex flex-col text-black-100  mt-5 border-t border-gray-100;
}

.footer__links-container {
  @apply flex max-md:flex-col flex-wrap justify-between gap-5 sm:px-16 px-6 py-10;
}

.footer__rights {
  @apply flex flex-col justify-start items-start gap-6;
}

.footer__links {
  @apply flex-1 w-full flex md:justify-end flex-wrap max-md:mt-10 gap-20;
}

.footer__link {
  @apply flex flex-col gap-6 text-base min-w-[170px];
}

.footer__copyrights {
  @apply flex justify-between items-center flex-wrap mt-10 border-t border-gray-100 sm:px-16 px-6 py-10;
}

.footer__copyrights-link {
  @apply flex-1 flex sm:justify-end justify-center max-sm:mt-4 gap-10;
}
/* END: Footer styles */

/* START: searchbar styles */
.searchbar {
  @apply flex items-center justify-start max-sm:flex-col w-full relative max-sm:gap-4 max-w-3xl;
}

.searchbar__item {
  @apply flex-1 max-sm:w-full flex justify-start items-center relative;
}

.searchbar__input {
  @apply w-full h-[48px] pl-12 p-4 bg-light-white rounded-r-full max-sm:rounded-full outline-none cursor-pointer text-sm;
}
/* END: searchbar styles */

/* START: search manufacturer styles */
.search-manufacturer {
  @apply flex-1 max-sm:w-full flex justify-start items-center;
}

.search-manufacturer__input {
  @apply w-full h-[48px] pl-12 p-4 rounded-l-full max-sm:rounded-full bg-light-white outline-none cursor-pointer text-sm;
}

.search-manufacturer__options {
  @apply absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm;
}

.search-manufacturer__option {
  @apply cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4;
}
/* END: search manufacturer styles */
```

tailwind.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        inter: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      },
      colors: {
        "black-100": "#2B2C35",
        "primary-blue": {
          DEFAULT: "#2B59FF",
          100: "#F5F8FF",
        },
        "secondary-orange": "#f79761",
        "light-white": {
          DEFAULT: "rgba(59,60,152,0.03)",
          100: "rgba(59,60,152,0.02)",
        },
        grey: "#747A88",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'pattern': "url('/pattern.png')",
        'hero-bg': "url('/hero-bg.png')"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.1.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is a path for a file where Tailwind classes don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the components you mention are in a `component` folder? As implied by:

```
import { Hero } from '@/component/template/index'
```

If so, you'd need to add this directory to your `content` array in the `tailwind.config.ts`. For example, if this `component` folder is in the root of your project, you'd do:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./component/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
```

Or as another example, if the folder is at `src/component`, then it would be:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/component/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
```

For further reading, consider the [Tailwind documentation on the `content` configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).